# how to bind sql data to a label in a dialog result vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, dialog, label

I am currently working in vb.net windows form applications, backed by an sql server. I am currently trying to load a dialog result and I need to auto load a label into the dialog result. However, whenever I try and bind the sql results into the label I am getting an error. I have done this before with data in a DGV that was loaded by an sql query but this one is giving me some issues. The error comes up when I attempt to load the variable "datareader" into "f.labelshear.text = datareader."

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles M01.Click

    Dim dr As DialogResult
    Dim f As New CellContent

    Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
        conn1.Open()
        Using comm1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT Shear FROM Production.dbo.tblFabWipLog WHERE FabWipID = 1", conn1)
            Dim datareader As SqlDataReader = comm1.ExecuteReader
            datareader.ToString()
            f.LabelShear.Text = datareader


        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final code

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles M01.Click
    Try
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
            conn1.Open()
            Using comm1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT Shear FROM Production.dbo.tblFabWipLog WHERE FabWipID = 1", conn1)
                Dim sqlda As New SqlDataAdapter(comm1)
                sqlda.Fill(dt)
                Dim dr As DialogResult
                Dim f As New CellContent
                f.LabelShear.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Shear").ToString
                f.ShowDialog()
                conn1.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that neither your first code and second code will work. 
After declaring datareader you had to code `datareader.Read()` then later on `f.LabelShear.Text = datareader(0).Tostring` for the binding to work.

Comment: Yea, you right, I got rid of the original error and thought I was good to go. I updated the code and get an object error now.

Comment: Final code is uploaded. I ended up having to load it into a datatable and then select based on my column name.